# WCF service and application pool

Tags: iis, wcf

I fixed a problem in a try and error way, I don't understand what I did and need explanation!!

When connecting to WCF service I got exception with message

The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

After a lot of trials related to IIS 6 configuration, I notice that the only application on the Default App pool is that WCF web service, I created App pool and assigned it to the service, it works!!  Why??!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, application pools operate under the `NetworkService` account.

I would suggest that the Default App pool had been set to run as `IWAM_SOMEUSER` and that user didnt have permissions to access your WCF service files, but `NetworkService` did.